# How to catch broken pipe for sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, ioexception, eofexception

I have written a Java client-server application using Sockets. I'm using the method `writeUnshared()` of`ObjectOutputStream` and `readObject()` of `ObjectInputStream`.

Now I would like to detect when the connection is broken to reconnnect (e.g. when Wifi signal was lost). Currently, for `ObjectInputStream` I'm catching `EOFException` and for `ObjectOutputStream` I'm catching `IOException` to detect if the pipe is borken.

Is this correct or should I catch `IOException` for both streams?

Comment: You should catch `IOException` for both streams. You will only get `EOFException` if the peer closed and the resulting transmissions succeeded. Not on a network failure. All `IOExceptions` other than `SocketTimeoutException` are fatal to the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go by the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), which recommends catching IOException for all of the usual I/O related exceptions.

Or you can go by your own testing.

Or you can go by the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java.html), which shows that when using "block data" mode EOFException is used by serialization whenever there is insufficient bytes to construct a full object.  However, that would not catch all cases in which the connection is broken.

All things considered, I would recommend IOException.